# Windows service onstop will kill the thread?

Tags: multithreading, windows-services

I have a windows service where I create a thread for doing the background process. So once the thread finishes the task, do I need to call the service ‘stop’ event to make the service stop? (like `this.stop()` in code)

I didn’t clearly understand why it’s asking to not write code in `onstart` event and asked to create a thread. Is it because the service will stop after a particular time? Will it cause my thread also to stop, when the service ends? Because I don’t need that. The thread should handle a long running process; I need the thread not killed until it finishes the task.

Comment: This is old but I have the same or similar question based on your subject.  The subject of your post is clear however your first question does not match your subject.  I can't  think of any reason to force onstop in code.  Doesn't sound like you need a service to do what you want.  The second question you ask above is much more interesting.  Paraphase: Do all threads created by onstart get killed when opstop fires?.  I would like to know this.  I am seeing my threads not complete after onstop fires on my windows service.

Comment: Actually, to answer my own question, onstop firing will not automatically kill running threads or threads created when a timer event fires.   I call System.Timers.Timer.Stop() in my winservice.onstop handler.  This operation seems to have the effect of stopping the currently executing timer handler method (while in the middle of doing something).  this I don't understand.